# How can I specify step definition file for each feature file in cucumber-js?

Tags: javascript, bdd, cucumberjs

## My Goal

I am trying to create a scalable structure of features and step definitions for a large application and my first shot was trying to link step_definition files to features so that I could use the same step pattern for different step definitions.

## My Code

I show my current example:

My folder structure:

```
/features/sample.feature
/features/example.feature
/features/step_definitions/sample_steps.js
/features/step_definitions/example_steps.js
/features/step_definitions/common/common_steps.js
```

In my `sample.feature` I have:

```
  Scenario: Launching Cucumber
  Given I have some step definitions
   When I check some step definition with parameter "any"
   Then I should see all green "sample"
```

In my `example.feature` I have:

```
  Scenario: Launching Cucumber
  Given I have some step definitions
   When I check some step definition with parameter "any"
   Then I should see all green "example"
```

The `Given` and `When` steps are defined at `/common/common_steps.js` file and works fine.

The `Then` step is defined both to `sample_steps.js` and `example_steps.js` but differently.

In my sample_steps.js I have:

```
Then('I should see all green {stringInDoubleQuotes}', (arg) => {
   if (arg !== 'sample') {
     throw 'I should see all green when the argument is "sample"';
   }
   return;
 });
```

And, finally, in my example_steps.js I have:

```
Then('I should see all green {stringInDoubleQuotes}', (arg) => {
   if (arg !== 'example') {
     throw 'I should see all green when the argument is "example"';
   }
   return;
 });
```

## The Error

My main goal is to have all green here, but of course, it doesn't work and I get this obviouly error:

```
Multiple step definitions match:
   I should see all green {stringInDoubleQuotes} - features\step_definitions\example_steps.js:6
   I should see all green {stringInDoubleQuotes} - features\step_definitions\sample_steps.js:6
```

## Cucumber-JVM

I know that in cucumber-jvm we can specify a `glue` attribute that links features and step_definitions and it's exactly what I'm looking for, but in cucumber-js. Example in Java:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options( glue = { "com.app.stepdefinitions.common", "com.app.stepdefinitions.sample" } )
public class SampleFeature{
}

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options( glue = { "com.app.stepdefinitions.common", "com.app.stepdefinitions.example" } )
public class ExampleFeature{
}
```

## Finally

How can I achieve the same as cucumbr-jvm using cucumber-js?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do this:

```
Then('I should see all green "sample"', () => {
   return;
 });


Then('I should see all green "example"', () => {
   return;
 });
```

The thing with step definitions in a larger codebase is that many steps are very similar. i.e: I navigate to "page" - you could put the code in a common place, and have the urls elsewhere.

Personally, I would do this:

```
Then('I should see all green "(.*)"', (arg) => {

 // DO SOME COMMON STUFF

 arg = arg.toLowerCase();
 if(arg === "sample"){
   // DO SAMPLE OWN STUFF
 }else if(arg === "example"){
   // DO EXAMPLE STUFF
 }

 // CARRY ON WITH COMMON STUFF
});
```

But this could get quite long. If they do completely different things, go with the first option, if they do pretty much the same thing, use the second one.

It may actually be that you only need to do this:

```
Then('I should see all green "(.*)"', (arg) => {

 // DO SOME COMMON STUFF
 arg = arg.toLowerCase();
 var result = runTheseSteps(arg);

 // CARRY ON WITH COMMON STUFF
});
```

**EDIT**

I've found a way that could do it. It would be a generic function, which isn't part of your requirements (I'm sorry), but I believe that it may be the only way to get it to work.

In your hooks:

```
this.Before(function (scenario, callback) {
    var tags = [];
    for(var i=0;i<scenario.getTags().length; i++ ){
        tags[i] = scenario.getTags()[i].getName();
    }
    global.scenarioTags = tags.join(", ");
    callback();
});
```

In your step definition:

```
this.Given(/^I should see all "(.*)"$/, function (arg) {

    if (scenarioTags.includes("@sample") != null) {
        // DO THE SAMPLE STUFF
    } else {
        // DO THE EXAMPLE STUFF
    }
});
```

While it leaves your step definition generic, it means you can put anything into the double quotes, and as long as you tag your scenario, the right code will run.

```
@sample
  Scenario: Launching Cucumber
   Given I have some step definitions
   When I check some step definition with parameter "any"
   Then I should see all green "sample"

@example
  Scenario: Launching Cucumber
   Given I have some step definitions
   When I check some step definition with parameter "any"
   Then I should see all green "example"
```

Comment: well... I'd like to avoid a super generic method which receives arguments because it makes the step too complex. Your first option is still what I'm doing right now. But it makes me put some technical words in the feature file to distinguish steps... :(

Comment: See my edit, it may be generic, but would do what you want until Cucumber gives a way to glue the actual step to a scenario.